# How do I update a custom Bugzilla field in a custom Bugzilla extension using Perl?

Tags: perl, bugzilla

I have a custom field in Bugzilla that I need to update after making a JSON call to another server after a bug has been updated.  I am able to make the call and get the response back, but attempting to update the bug is failing.

I have tried setting the field in the hooks `bug_end_of_update` and `object_end_of_set_all` and it hasn't worked at all.  If I attempt to do it in `bug_end_of_update`, the object itself gets updated in memory, but it will never get set in the database.  Calling update on the `$bug` object in that method sends Bugzilla into an infinite loop that requires a complete restart to fix.  In the code below, I am able to update the `assigned_to` field correctly.  Using the same exact call doesn't work for a custom field though.

```perl
sub object_end_of_set_all {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;

    my $object = $args->{'object'};

    if ($object->isa('Bugzilla::Bug')) {        
        $object->{'assigned_to'} = $object->{'reporter_id'};    #this works
        $object->{'cf_custom_field'} = 'hello world';         #this doesn't
        my $blessedField = {cf_custom_field};
        bless $blessedField;
        $object->set($blessedField, 'hello world');         #also doesn't work
        $object->update;                                    #puts bugzilla into an infinite loop that never returns
    }
}
```

I would expect setting a custom field would work exactly like `assigned_to`, but it doesn't and the documentation on this is extremely lacking.

Comment: My first thought would be: `assigned_to` is a pre-defined field. Where is the piece of code where your announce to/extend/configure `Bug::Buzilla` that you are adding a field *also* needs to go to the database? I'm pretty sure just adding a key to the object hash can't be enough,

Comment: Maybe use [set_custom_field](https://github.com/bugzilla/bugzilla/blob/5.0/Bugzilla/Bug.pm#L2558)?

Comment: @StefanBecker I don't have any code that specifically tells it to go back to the database at all.  I was mostly just following the examples in the example extension perl file provided by Bugzilla and didn't see that anywhere.

Comment: @choroba I tried using the set_custom_field as you suggested without success.  What I tried with the accompanying errors are below:
$bug->set_custom_field(cf_custom_field, 'hello world'); #Can't locate object method "custom" via package "cf_custom_field" (perhaps you forgot to load "cf_custom_field"?) at Bugzilla/Bug.pm line 2364.
$bug->set_custom_field({cf_custom_field}, 'hello world'); #Can't call method "custom" on unblessed reference at Bugzilla/Bug.pm line 2364.

Comment: The first parameter to `set_custom_field` must be a field object.

Comment: OK I changed it to the below and it stopped erroring, but still does not update the actual bug.  I should add, changing the assign_to field only worked in object_end_of_set_all hook.
    my $field = new Bugzilla::Field({ name => 'cf_custom_field' }); 
    $object->set_custom_field($field, 'hello world');

Comment: [Bugzilla::Field](https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Field.html#SYNOPSIS) says `my $field = Bugzilla::Field->create({name => 'cf_silly', description => 'Silly', custom => 1});` with `name` and `description` being mandatory.

Comment: [Bug.pm:2364](https://git.lysator.liu.se/lysator/bugzilla/blob/release-4.4/Bugzilla/Bug.pm#L2364) says that non-custom fields cause `set_custom_field()` to throw an error.

Comment: If I try to use the Field->create, I get an exception saying the custom field has already been created (it has, I did it through the UI).

Comment: [Bugzilla::Field](https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Field.html#SYNOPSIS) again: `my $field = new Bugzilla::Field({name => 'cf_custom_field'});`. I assume as you have already created it as custom field, `$field->{custom}` should be true then.

Comment: That is correct, $field->{custom} returns as 1.  Calling $object->set_custom_field($field, 'hello world'); or $object->set($field, 'hi'); immediately after still has no impact on the actual bug.